# Returning Values of Varying Length Between Two Characters with VBS

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to come up with a method for extracting information from a file heading. The overall naming convention of the file heading will remain the same but portions of the heading will vary in character length. Below are two possible examples of such file headings:

1. 012345678-012345-xxxx-yyyyy.txt
2. 012345678-012345-xxx-yyyyyy.txt

Is there a way to extract values from these file headings such that it returns whatever appears between the second and third hyphen? Using the examples above it would return:

1. xxxx
2. xxx

Furthermore, is it possible to extract the values between the final hyphen and the period? Using the example above it would return:

1. yyyyy
2. yyyyyy

Extracting values is trivial when the character lengths are fixed, but I don't know if it's possible to do a similar extraction when the character lengths vary. I would normally use something like this to extract the information from a fixed-length naming convention but don't know how to adapt it to something where the character lengths change. For example, the snippet below is a function which extract the first nine characters in a file heading (in this case it would extract '012').

```
Function getthething(foo)
getthething = Mid(foo,1,3)
End Function
```

Any guidance would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the [Split Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function).

Comment: As @ÉtienneLaneville has suggested if you have a consistent separator between the values you can use something like `data = Split(value, "-")`  to return an array of the varying values in the order they appeared, i.e `data(0)` would be the first value and `data(3)` would be the last value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all of this using the [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/0764e5w5(v=vs.84)) function. Here's a wrapper function that simplifies things:

```
Function GetField(p_sText, p_sDelimiter, p_iIndex)

    Dim arrFields
    
    arrFields = Split(p_sText, p_sDelimiter)
    
    If UBound(arrFields) >= (p_iIndex - 1) Then
        GetField = arrFields(p_iIndex - 1)
    Else
        GetField = ""
    End If

End Function
```

You can use this function like this:

```
Dim sFileName
Dim sYs

sFileName = GetField("012345678-012345-xxxx-yyyyy.txt", ".", 1)
sYs = GetField(sFileName, "-", 4)

MsgBox sYs
```

or simply:

```
MsgBox GetField(GetField("012345678-012345-xxxx-yyyyy.txt", ".", 1), "-", 4)
```

Comment: Not a fan of changing index away from 0 based ordinals as that's how VBScript arrays work, or the use of Hungarian Notation but good answer regardless. Shame the question doesn't deserve it.

Comment: Thanks @Étienne Laneville. This is honestly way over my head. Need to go through this for a while to see if I can make it work.